# Saving imported data to Core Data - Can't read back

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

When my application first runs I'm using some simple code to read in some data from a source and then saving it to core data to be read back in the future.  Here is my applicationDidFinishLaunching method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (![defaults objectForKey:@"dataImported"]) {
        NSMutableArray *temp_Categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Food & Drink", @"Medical", @"Hotel", @"Travel", nil];

        for(int i = 0; i < [temp_Categories count]; i++){
            //Insert a new object of type ProductInfo into Core Data
            NSManagedObject *categoryInfo = [NSEntityDescription
                                              insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Category" 
                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

            //Set category entities values
            [categoryInfo setValue:[temp_Categories objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"categoryName"];

            [categories addObject:[temp_Categories objectAtIndex:i]];
        }

        [defaults setObject:@"OK" forKey:@"dataImported"];
        [defaults synchronize];

        NSLog(@"Imported");
    }
    else {
        //read from core data
        NSError *error;
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                                       entityForName:@"Category" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        NSMutableArray *temp_Categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]];

        for (int i = 0; i < [temp_Categories count]; i++){
            NSString *category = [[temp_Categories objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"categoryName"];
            [categories addObject:category];
            NSLog(@"Success");
        }

        NSLog(@"Read From Core");
    }

    return YES;
}
```

When I run this code the very first time, it works correctly, however when I run it in future (when it read from core data) it does not work, it doesn't read in the array from core data and temp_Categories count = 0.  Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?  I'm having the same trouble trying to do the same thing with a plist file in another app.

Thanks,

Jack

**EDIT 1**   I'm using iOS 5.

**EDIT 2**  Data model screenshot:[image: Data Model]

Comment: do you get any warning at this line??



 NSMutableArray *temp_Categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]];

Comment: Try this line : NSMutableArray *temp_Categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]mutableCopy];

Comment: Also have you created data model correctly?? If possible show screenshot of your datamodel.

Comment: It doesn't like that line at all "Expected :" error.  I should mention I'm using iOS 5.

Comment: iOS 5 won't affect your core data. I also implemented it for iOS5.. Try my answer i hope it will help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work with this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (![defaults objectForKey:@"dataImported"]) {
        NSMutableArray *temp_Categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Food & Drink", @"Medical", @"Hotel", @"Travel", nil];

        for(int i = 0; i < [temp_Categories count]; i++){
            //Insert a new object of type Category into Core Data
            NSManagedObject *categoryInfo = [NSEntityDescription
                                             insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Category" 
                                             inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

            //Set category entities values
            [categoryInfo setValue:[temp_Categories objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"name"];

            NSError *error;
            if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }

            NSLog(@"Added category to Core Data");

            //Add to global array
            [categories addObject:[temp_Categories objectAtIndex:i]];
        }

        [defaults setObject:@"OK" forKey:@"dataImported"];
        [defaults synchronize];

        NSLog(@"Imported");
    }
    else {
        //read from core data
        NSError *error;
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                                       entityForName:@"Category" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        NSMutableArray *temp_Categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]];

        for (NSManagedObject *object in temp_Categories){
            [categories addObject: [object valueForKey:@"name"]];
        }

        NSLog(@"Read From Core");
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to you call

```
NSError* error = nil;
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to save: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}
```

after inserting your object...

Answer (score 0):

You should call save method..  To save the changes to `persistent store` you have to call `save` method . Until then the changes are just temporary present on your `scratch board/ ManagedObjectContext`.

Add save method after this line:

```
[categoryInfo setValue:[temp_Categories objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"categoryName"];
```

**Save Method:**

```
 NSError *error;

if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
{
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

also I do not know this line works correctly or not in else part..

```
 NSString *category = [[temp_Categories objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"categoryName"];
```

Try this line instead..

```
    Category *currentCategory = (Category *)[temp_Categories objectAtIndex:i];
    [categories addObject:currentCategory.categoryName];
```